# python: how to download sentence-transformers model with proxy?

Tags: python, huggingface, sentence-transformers

```
from sentence_transformers import CrossEncoder

cross_encoder = CrossEncoder('cross-encoder/ms-marco-MiniLM-L-6-v2')
```

I am getting error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='cdn-lfs.huggingface.co', port=443): Read timed out.
Downloading pytorch_model.bin:   0%|          | 0.00/90.9M [01:34<?, ?B/s]
```

how to setup proxy just for this two lines, don't affect other code,

Comment: To set up a proxy specifically for those two lines and not affect other code, you can use the `proxies` parameter from the `requests` library.